# How does Evade/Dodge/Block trigger?

Tags: actions, four-color-system

I'm a bit confused on how it triggers. Can you *always* use these, or do you have to take an action beforehand to use these (and if so do they count vs. all enemies of the turn or only vs. 1), ... ?

Rules system is: 4C (Four Color System): It is an OGL/public-domain successor to the old percentile Marvel RPG system (with enough changes to essentially be a 2nd edition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You (always) declare/state your actions during the turn (abstract time that fits into a single comic book panel)

> A character can perform any action that would fit into a standard
> panel including attack, dodge, or move.

and act according to initiative (p. 21). You repeat that 6-step combat process until the combat is over.

Evade is for melee combat only, to see the different d% roll tables for block and evade read p. 26 (Advanced combat section), and p. 25 for dodging.

Dodging works, unless a failure, against:

> Anyone attacking you this turn

Blocking works, unless a failure, against:

> the attacker’s Brawn

Evade works, unless a failure, against:

> You successfully evade the attack

Comment: Ah there was the error.....I overread that you PREdeclare your actions. then it makes sense at long last.  Thanks

Comment: @ThomasE.  it is a little unintuitive, when you win initiative, you can use Waiting to optimise timing which makes combat even weirder at times.